# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004] .NET6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a webapi with ASP.NET CORE which is running on my local system(MacOS) and dockerized a Microsoft SQL Server. I have everything set up and added hangfire to the project which connects to the Dockerized SQL server and works without issue.

In this project the HangfireDB is the main database while, HangFire is the Schema. Also where the GithubRepos table is.


### Setup

I have added the context to the Program.cs in the project as shown below.

```
var gitRepo = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("GitRepoConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GithubContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(gitRepo));
```

The connection string is in the appsettings.json

```
"GitRepoConnection": "Server=localhost,4022;Database=HangfireDB;User Id=sa;Password=P@$$w0rd;"
```

This is the GithubContext.cs Class

```
public class GithubContext : DbContext
{
    public GithubContext(DbContextOptions<GithubContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<GithubRepo> GithubRepos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure default schema
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("HangFire");
    }
}
```

The command I used to launch the SQL Server

```
docker run \
--name=SQL_DB \
--detach \
-e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \
-e "SA_PASSWORD=P@$$w0rd" \
--publish 4022:1433 \
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU15-ubuntu-20.04
```

The migrations commands used

```
dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
dotnet ef database update
```

### Error

The only issue is this error message that I'm getting which is when im trying to populate a table.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'HangfireDB' on server 'localhost,4022'.
```

Comment: Check the connection string in the appsettings.json file, try to change the connection string from `"GitRepoConnection": "Server=localhost,4022....` to `"GitRepoConnection": "Server=localhost:4022....`. Before the port, it should be a `:`,

Comment: I have tried to do that and now the error message is as follows `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''.
`

Answer (score 1):

Try to run with this docker-compose, the key is assign the root user and create folder in which MSSQL creates the data.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    user: root
    ports:
      - 4022:1433
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data/
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@$$w0rd
```

According to documentation SA_PASSWORD is decrecated instead, we should use MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD.

My scenario is Windows WSL and it works.

The connection string looks like:

```
"Server=localhost,4022;Database=YourDB;User ID=sa;Password=P@$$w0rd;"
```

Answer (score 0):

change ConnectString from your db to **host.docker.internal** instead localhost and make sure you have sql container